# Error in Microsoft Bot Emulator: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, botframework, bots

I'm getting this error when trying to log the `.bot` file into the Microsoft Bot Emulator. Error name:

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3978

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error only appears if Emulator is unable to connect to your bot. Here's what you can do to troubleshoot (from most likely to least):

1. Verify that your bot is running. You need to execute `npm start` from the root directory to run a Javascript bot. It's almost definitely this.
2. Sometimes, you might run `npm start` but the bot won't run because the port is in use (you're running another bot) or your bot has an error that prevents it from running. It's also possible that you didn't install the npm packages with `npm install` after first downloading the bot.
3. Ensure that you selected the right `.bot` file in emulator. Really, though, you can use any `.bot` file in the Emulator so long as it isn't encrypted and the endpoint matches. Make sure that the "development" endpoint in your `.bot` file is `http://localhost:3978`

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the project in Visual Studio? You seem to only have visual studio code open. You need to run the project to be able to connect to the endpoint.

Comment: You're on the right track, but he's running a Javascript/Node bot and that can be run in VS Code by opening the terminal and running `npm start`